# Replacing a template with PHP and regex

Tags: php, regex

I need to do use php/regex to replace this:

```
{{image-4-m}}
```

to this:

```
<img src="4.jpg" class="m" />
```

or another example, this:

```
{{image-53-v}}
```

to this:

```
<img src="53.jpg" class="v" />
```

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reference groups by index with `preg_replace` by using `$n`.

```
preg_replace('/{{image-(\d+)-([mv])}}/', '<img src="$1.jpg" class="$2" />', $template);
```

[Here's a demo.](http://codepad.org/UIh0zCJj)